# removeTodo action not removing from state

Tags: javascript, react-redux, action, reducers

I am not sure where I am going wrong here, but when I trigger my removeTodo action, nothing happens. I believe it is a passing error on my part, but I can't quite figure it out. I thought that by setting my action to take in a todo as its payload, then in my dispatch I feed that action a todo.id, it could the remove said id. Cannot quite figure out why this won't work.

TodoItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeTodo } from '../actions';
import '../../css/Todo.css';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      removeTodo: todo => dispatch(removeTodo(todo.id))
    };
  };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {todos: [...state.todos]};
};

class ConnectedTodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {handleToggle, todoId} = this.props;
    const mappedTodos = this.props.todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <div className='todo-item'>
        <span onClick={handleToggle} index={index} id={todoId}>
          {todo.title}
        </span>
        <button type='submit' className='rem-btn' id={todoId} onClick={this.props.removeTodo}>X</button>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      mappedTodos
    );
  }
}

const TodoItem = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (ConnectedTodoItem);

export default TodoItem;
```

reducers.js

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../constants/action-types'; 
import { REMOVE_TODO } from '../constants/action-types';
import uuidv1 from 'uuid';

const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos,
          {
            title: action.payload.inputValue,
            id: uuidv1()
          }]
    }

    case REMOVE_TODO:
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.payload)]
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

actions.js

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../constants/action-types';
import { REMOVE_TODO } from '../constants/action-types';

export const addTodo = (todo) => (
  {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    payload: todo
  }
);

export const removeTodo = (todo) => (
  {
    type: REMOVE_TODO,
    payload: todo.id
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like the issue is with the way you're calling `removeTodo`

As you can see the function accepts a `todo` argument from which the the id is then extracted.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    removeTodo: todo => dispatch(removeTodo(todo.id))
  };
};
```

However you're not passing in the todo here.

```
onClick={this.props.removeTodo}
```

Try this instead:

```
onClick={() => this.props.removeTodo(todo)}
```

Update, to continue William's train of thought. I would do the following, passing around the `id` specifically rather than the whole object. It makes it a little easier to understand what you're updating then.

1) Dispatch function

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    removeTodo: id => dispatch(removeTodo(id))
  };
};
```

2) Call function

```
onClick={() => this.props.removeTodo(todoId)}
```

3) Action

```
export const removeTodo = (id) => (
  {
    type: REMOVE_TODO,
    id
  }
)
```

4) Reducer

```
case REMOVE_TODO: {
  return {
    ...state,
    todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok I see what you did there. Thanks for the quick response! I'm going to try implementing this into my code.

Comment: I thought that my dispatch ```const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    removeTodo: todo => dispatch(removeTodo(todo.id))
  };
};```
would use that `todo.id` when called in the map, which would pull that todo.id for each element. So if instead I just did this ```const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    removeTodo: todo => dispatch(removeTodo(todo))
  };
};```
would i then have to say `onClick={() => this.props.removeTodo(todo.id)}`?
Would that work too? Just for the sake of understanding this a little better.

Comment: @ColeGonzales, I've updated my answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto Andy's answer, it seems like you're also extracting the id in the dispatch call but you already do that in the actions.js where you define removeTodo, so unless you have a nested id inside todo.id, you'll want to remove it from either place.